# C printf with N leading zeroes

Tags: c, printf

I know that I could use `printf(%Nd, foo)` if N is constant and I know it
But the problem is that N is in variable and calculated in program

I could do it with combining `sprintf` and `printf`:

```
sprintf(formatstr, "%%%dd", N);
printf(formatstr, foo);
```

But is there any cleaner way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a `*` in place of the field width.  This means the next parameter will specify the width:

```
printf("%0*d", size, foo);
```